# How to save chechbox list in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to save the ids of the checkboxs list but I got this error:

Call to a member function sector() on a non-object

Code:
Criteria Model :

```
 public function sector(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector');


    }
```

Sector Model :

```
 public function criterion(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Criteria');
    }
```

CriterionController

```
$criteria = $request->all();
$sectorsIds = $request->input('sectors');
foreach($sectorsIds as $id ){
           $criteria->sector()->attach($id);
           }
```

sector Ids request array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "3"
  1 => "6"
  2 => "4"
]
```

Comment: the problem is that $criteria = $request->all() is not set correctly as a Criteria object. What are you expecting in $request->all() ? You need to find existing criteria in database first correctly. I don't think $request->all() will find the criteria in database. Are you sending criteria_id in the request ?

Comment: Yes you are right the error was on the $criteria 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `$criteria` should be

```
$criteria = Criteria::create($request->all());
```

Instead of

```
$criteria = $request->all();
```